# Stored procedure MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I was finishing advanced IBM Task using MySQL about stored procedures,

The following code cannot be executed , It counters an error in syntax

I have table `public_school` & column  `schoolID` (should be INT) & column `Leaders_Score` (should be INT)

I want to update a column  `Leaders_Icon` as it changed with the change of the score itself by using (`CASE-END` )

THE CODE IS :

```
DELIMITER @
  
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (in_School_ID INT, in_Leader_Score INT) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE public_school
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    CASE
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >=80 THEN 
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Very_Strong"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >= 60 and in_Leaders_Score <= 79  
        THEN
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Strong"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >=  40 and in_Leaders_Score <=  59
        THEN
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Average"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >=  20 and in_Leaders_Score <=  39 
        THEN
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Weak"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        ELSE
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Very Weak"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    END
END @
  
DELIMITER ;
```

By the way - MySQL gives error red sign beside -- (END @)

I do not know what I have done wrong , or what should I do next

Comment: You should use one update and one Leaders_icon = case when ... when .. else end. There is no need in stored procedure at all.

Comment: @arheops This is an academic exercise in writing SP. The fact that it can be done without the SP is not really relevant.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with Workbench. What happens when you try to run the code, do you get an error message?

Comment: it gives syntax error , but when I remove the @ sign from END , the whole page does not executeded at all not even with an error

Comment: I already played with ALTER TABLE , MODIFY , and using the UPDATE, SET and all other functions , but it is the task say like this

Comment: When you have issue with your excersice, always try simpler example first. For example one update. Check case with select etc. Anyway, quality of your answer is really bad because you are doing the same task in the case. Hard to maintain, hard to check and hard to find errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to end a `CASE` statement with `END CASE`, not just `END`. And you need a `;` after the statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (in_School_ID INT, in_Leader_Score INT) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE public_school
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    CASE
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >=80 THEN 
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Very_Strong"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >= 60 and in_Leaders_Score <= 79  
        THEN
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Strong"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >=  40 and in_Leaders_Score <=  59
        THEN
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Average"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        WHEN in_Leaders_Score >=  20 and in_Leaders_Score <=  39 
        THEN
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Weak"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        ELSE
            UPDATE public_school
            SET Leaders_Icon = "Very Weak"
            WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    END CASE;
END @
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maysara - here is a shorter version without **CASE**

```
DELIMITER @

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE ( IN in_School_ID INT, IN in_Leader_Score INT) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE public_school
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score,
        Leaders_Icon  = ELT( LEAST(( in_Leader_Score div 20 )+1, 5)
        , "Very Weak", "Weak" , "Average", "Strong", "Very_Strong")    
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    
END @

DELIMITER ;
```